# Xna text having extra space between characters

Tags: windows, fonts, xna, spritefont

I'm making a new game, and I want to use my own textures for texts. I came across this cool tool called SpriteFont 2.0, which is like a WYSIWYG editor for making texture files for SpriteFont files in XNA. I made this font:[image: My font texture]

But my problem is that when I put it into XNA, there is A LOT of extra space between letters. For example, this was supposed to say, "This is a test", but it turned out like this:[image]

Is there something wrong with my texture file, or is there something I need to do with my programming. I just used the first DrawString method in the `SpriteBatch` object. I changed the Content import for the texture file to Sprite Font Texture, too. I don't know why the text has so much space between characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could change the [Spacing property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritefont.spacing(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) of your SpriteFont object at runtime. Set it to a negative value and see if the letters are closer together.

```
SpriteFont myFont = ...;
myFont.Spacing = -10;
```

Alternately, if the editor has kerning settings, that's what you would really want. Kerning is defining the spacing between letters, like so:

[image: Kerning example]

---

There is also a [LineSpacing property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritefont.linespacing(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) for vertical height which you might also want to tweak, if you print multiple lines to the screen (as one draw call).

Comment: But Im not using a .spritefont file. You can make a font texture inside a paint editor, sort of like a sprite sheet. Then just change the way Visual Studio builds it. Because all that Visual Studio does with the .spritefont files is turn them into Bitmaps. SpriteFont 2.0 has a spacing property, but that doesnt change anything, as far as I can see.

Comment: @cakeisajoke Unfortunately the build-time settings for `SpriteFont`s are very limited. But what Ricket has linked are **runtime** settings. Which you can set on your `SpriteFont` object after you load it... With a bit of trickery you can build custom `SpriteFont` content - with full control over spacing, kerning, etc - even though there's no official way in XNA. Look at Nuclex Fonts for an example. But it's rather complicated - so the runtime solution is probably your best bet.

Comment: Of course, what @Ricket wrote about modifying `.spritefont` files doesn't apply to your question at all. And there's no runtime way to modify the kerning setting. Perhaps an edit, Ricket?

Comment: @cakeisajoke As Andrew pointed out, Spacing is also a runtime property. I edited to show an example of how you'd set it. Maybe it'll work for you?

Comment: Hey! Your right, I can change some of the SpriteFont properties by changing the variable I load it in. Thanks!